# Problema al optimizar unos datos bajo condicional python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, dataframe

He creado un código el cual extrae desde una base de datos de Excel ciertos valores en función de los datos **‘ingreso_datos[i][2] y ingreso_datos[i][3]’** para almacenarlos en una lista **‘base’** a dichos datos luego los relaciono para obtener un valor **‘R’.**

```
import pandas as pd 

ingreso_datos = [[1, 'Col', 'D', '21X62'],
                [2, 'Col', 'D', '12X62'],
                [3, 'Col', 'D', '21X68'],
                [4, 'Col', 'D', '21X62'],
                [5, 'Row', 'D', '12X45'],
                [6, 'Row', 'D', '12X45']]

ExcelPrincipal = pd.ExcelFile('ejemplo.xlsx')
base = []
for i in range(len(ingreso_datos)): 

    if ingreso_datos[i][2] == 'A':
        data = ExcelPrincipal.parse('A') 

    elif ingreso_datos[i][2] == 'D':
        data = ExcelPrincipal.parse('D') 

    for j in range(len(data)):
        if ingreso_datos[i][3] == data.values[j][0]:
            base.append([data.values[j][1], data.values[j][2]])     

print('Elemento',5*' ','Relación')
R_list = []
for i in range(len(ingreso_datos)):
    if ingreso_datos[i][1] == 'Col':
        R = round(base[i][1]/base[i][0],3) 
        R_list.append(R)

        print(f"{i+1:02} {R:>18}")    

#while R_list[i] < 0.5:
#    
#    for j in range(len(R_list)):
#        if ingreso_datos[i][1] == 'Col':
#            R = round(base[i][1]/base[i][0],3) 
#            R_list.append(R)
```

Ahora estoy intentando hacer que los valores de **‘R’** superen el umbral de **0.5**, para ello es necesario buscar de la **‘data’** los valores que hagan que se supere ese umbral. He pensado en un bucle While, que evalúe los valores de **R_list**, pero pienso que se podría optimizar de mejor manera. ¿Existe alguna mejor solución al respecto?

Busco que al imprimirse supere dicho umbral

```
Elemento       Relación
01              > 0.5
02              > 0.5
03              > 0.5
04              > 0.5
```

Saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes quitar el bucle `while` perfectamente, añadir la condición 0.5 y quedar el resto, es decir:

```
for j in range(len(R_list)):
    if ingreso_datos[i][1] == 'Col' and > 0.5:
    R = round(base[i][1]/base[i][0],3) 
    R_list.append(R)
```